# How to retrieve Business Component rows in SIebel Open UI PM?

Tags: javascript, crm, siebel

How can I get field values of BC from Presentation Model in Siebel Open UI?

I was trying:

```
SiebelApp.S_App.Model.GetBusObj("").GetBusComp("")
```

but Model is not recognized. I also tried creating model with `GetModel()` function, but it didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access any BC in the Active View,you can do that via the [Get](http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2014/09/what-you-can-get-from-open-ui-literally.html) method of the PM, eg: GetRecordSet will give you an array of variables.

See this example to see how you 
can [GetFieldValue](http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2015/03/displaying-the-number-of-child-records-in-siebel-crm.html)

If you need to access some other BCs not in the activeView, you have to go via eScript BS. This is kind of a security layer, even the older Browser script system had this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

As I researched in oracle support there is no way to directly access repository objects via PM. We should create Business Service to deal with this part.

Answer (score 0):

BusCom has several method to work on business layer in OpenUI. 
few Examples are as below.

```
BusCom = this.GetPM().Get("BusCom")
pm.Get("GetBusComp").GetBusObj()
pm.Get("GetBusComp").GetName();
pm.Get("GetBusComp").GetFieldMap()
pm.Get("GetBusComp").GetNumRows() // NumberOfRecords
pm.Get("GetBusComp").GetParentBusComp().GetName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access records of other business component using OpenUI.

OpenUI is for current View and available business components.

if you want to retrieve current row then you can use getrecordset or showselection.