# OpenUI Get List of Values

Tags: controls, siebel, lov

I am looking for a smart solution how to retrieve the Data from a LoV from a Business Component of Siebel. I tried to read the control with,...

```
var controls = this.GetPM().Get("GetControls");
for(var control in controls){
   var value = this.GetPM().ExecuteMethod("GetFieldValue", controls[control]);
}
```

And with,...

```
this.GetPM().Get("GetRecordSet");
```

But the result for a LoV is still "". Is there a way without a Business Service to get the List of Values?

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenUI, but assuming "this" is an applet instance... wouldn't the usual `this.BusComp().GetFieldValue("Field Name");` work?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/30346461/3690032 I dont have direct access to the repository objects. So i dont think so :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search we got following answer,...

> At the moment it is not possible. The problem is that the PM can only
>   see the active values of the Applet. The LoV (select in HTML) is
>   getting generated as soon the client clicks active on the select
>   element.

We build now a Business Service (BS) that provides the List of Values that i need to render.

Kind regards,
Myracle